# How does the Apache Camel OPC-UA Client connection to a Keystore work?

Tags: apache-camel, opc-ua, milo

I'm new to Apache Camel. I develop an application which is based on Camel. At the moment I'm working with the **OPC-UA** part of **Camel** which is based on **Eclipse Milo**.
I need to use certificates to connect my application (which is the OPC-UA client) to an OPC-UA Server. At the moment the server side doesn't use a **Keystore** for their certificates (it's a non productive environment). However it's not possible to laod local certificates into my client with Camel. According to their documentation they only offer the way over a Keystore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmuSJ.png)

Now my question is how exactly does the connection to a Keystore work with Camel? Because I only see a parameter to specify an URL to a Keystore. I have only worked with local Kestores (from a java sdk/ jre for example).

Are there any projects for self hosting a keystore (which would be available in my network) to test this connection?

I tried to load a key from a local Keystore but without success.

Comment: Have you tried a file URL? `file://path/to/file`...